# R argparse: Line breaks in description

Tags: r, argparse

I'm using the R package [argparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/index.html) to parse command line arguments in an R script.

For readability, I'd like to add line breaks in the "description" of the script and in the help of the arguments. However, I can't do it... Let's see an example. Given this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

require(argparse)

docstring<- "Description\nDone"

parser<- ArgumentParser(description= docstring)
args<- parser$parse_args()
```

When executed with *-h* it should print:

```
Description
Done
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Error in rjson::fromJSON(output) : unexpected character 'F'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Variation of docstring like *paste("Description", "Done", sep= '\n')* are equally unsuccessful.

**EDIT**: Passing RawTextHelpFormatter: No luck.

```
parser<- ArgumentParser(description= docstring, RawTextHelpFormatter= TRUE)
```

Any idea how to put line breaks in argparse?

Many thanks!

Dario

**NB**: Cross posted on r-help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-November/423722.html

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] argparse_1.0.1 proto_0.3-10  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] findpython_1.0.1 getopt_1.20.0    rjson_0.2.13
```

Comment: The Python `argparse` has a couple of `Raw` help formatter classes that preserve line breaks.  The default formatter does its own line wrapping.  Were those other formatters ported to `R`?

Comment: Thanks for replying hpaulj. I tried your suggestion but no success (see edit to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while playing around and looking at the code, I found the solution to my own answer: Use `formatter_class= 'argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter'` and properly escape newline characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

require(argparse)

docstring<- "DESCRIPTION \\n\\
Do stuff \\n\\n\\
Do more stuff"

parser<- ArgumentParser(description= docstring, formatter_class= 'argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter')
args<- parser$parse_args()
```

Now it correctly gives (startup messages omitted):

```
./testParse.R -h
usage: ./testParse.R [-h]

DESCRIPTION 
Do stuff 

Do more stuff

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

@hpaulj your hint was correct it took me a while to figure it out!